# How to Query Cookie Variables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

I'm trying to create a mysql/php chat (private message) for my site using the "WHERE" clause in PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM (tablename) WHERE (columnname) = $_SESSION('MM_USERNAME')
```

However, I seem to only be able to search for plain text or my table "users.username" which brings up all results in table (not what I want). Is it possible to search from the username cookie variable?

Comment: Sometimes a code sample speaks more than a thousand words.

Comment: You need to quote strings... Try echoing the code you're trying to run and running it on the DB direectly.

Comment: $query_chat = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE chat.to_user = echo '$_SESSION('MM_Username')' "; Also doesn't work

Comment: 1. Why are you using `echo`? 2. I believe it should be `$_SESSION['xxx']`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `columnname` = '".$_SESSION['MM_USERNAME']."'";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$_SESSION('MM_USERNAME')` is a string it needs to be in quotes.

```
$query_chat = "SELECT * FROM (tablename) WHERE (columnname) = '" . $_SESSION['MM_USERNAME'] . "'";
```

Using the error reporting of which ever driver you are using should return this to you. You also should be sure you sanatize that value or use a prepared statement.

Comment: Just brings up a blank screen in browser.

Comment: Try update just noticed SESSION wasn't being accessed as an array  and/or post all your PHP.